# How does a digital signature handle big-integers?

Tags: python, hash, digital-signature, biginteger

How does a digital signature handle big-integers?

For complexity, digital signatures use big-integers as parameters.
[image: step of sign a digital signature]

From the picture above, except for variable `a`, all variables are (or can be) big-integers. When a signature needs to be verified, how does one handle computational problems?
[image]

`Ya`,`S1`,`S2` and `q` are big-integers. It is real hard to claculate between big-integers. There has be a way to reduce the calculation time otherwise people cannot use a digital signature.

Does anyone know how to deal with big-integers??

Comment: Note that calculating a power, `mod q`, can be done by reducing each intermediate product `mod q` immediately - so no truly huge numbers ever need to be worked with.  Python implements this as the 3-parameter version of `pow()`.

Comment: Please do not put code, data, formulas, error messages, or text information as a picture. Text in images can be very difficult to read, especially on mobile (it also takes more data to download), and it's impossible to copy-paste image text into search engines and code editors.  As per [SO guidelines](StackOverflow.com/help), please edit your question accordingly. You can use markdown's code formatting or table formatting, to improve readability. You might be able to use latex formatting, too, but I don't recall for sure.

Comment: Never mind. According to a comment on this [StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/implement-an-api-call-to-display-latex-as-inline-image) latex is only implemented on a few StackExchange sites, StackOverflow is not one of them. :-(. Perhaps an image is the only viable solution for some formulas, after all.

Comment: I already edit my question and try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I found a solution.
The idea is using pow() with three parameters.
The original formula is:

```
    v2 = (pow(y_a,s1)*pow(s1,s2))%q
```

When pow() function only has two parameters, it not as fast as it has three parameters. In this case pow() only has y_a and s1 two parameters.

The new formula is:

```
    v2 = pow(y_a,s1,q)%q * pow(s1,s2,q)%q
```

Making pow() has three parameters, the calculation speed has been increased dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

What you call "big-integer", also called "bignum" arithmetic, is indeed slow, in terms of CPU cycle per byte processed, comparing to symmetric encryption like AES. But, in public key cryptography, e.g. in digital signatures, the protocols are designed in such a way that minimize the use of bignum arithmetic. For example, to make a digital signature of a very big message, the bignum arithmetic is not applied over the whole message. Instead, the message is first compressed by a cryptographically strong hash function that produces a small digest, of, for example, 384 bits. Then, the bignum arithmetic is only applied to this small digest. The hash functions are very fast. For intance, on an Intel SkyLake CPU released in 2015, like Core i7 6700K, a hash function takes approximately the following number of CPU cycles per byte of message: [MD5 - 5](https://github.com/maximmasiutin/MD5_Transform-x64), SHA1 - 4, SHA2-384 - 5, SHA3-384 - 11.

The same is in the other security protocols based on public key cryptography, like in TLS: bignum arithmetic is only used at the beginning of the session, while further data transfer does not involve the bignum arithmetic. And there are extensions to the TLS protocols for "Session Resumption" that help further decrease the use of bignum arithmetic.

> In computer science, arbitrary-precision arithmetic, also called
> bignum arithmetic, multiple-precision arithmetic, or sometimes
> infinite-precision arithmetic, indicates that calculations are
> performed on numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the
> available memory of the host system. This contrasts with the faster
> fixed-precision arithmetic found in most arithmetic logic unit (ALU)
> hardware, which typically offers between 8 and 64 bits of precision.
> [(source: Wikipedia article on Arbitrary-precision arithmetic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)

Some programming languages ​​require a library to handle large number arithmetic, while other languages ​​have the library built in. For example, you can directly use the Python programming language to perform arithmetic operations on large numbers without worrying about linking a library. Python supports the "bignum" integer type, which can handle arbitrarily large numbers. In Python version 2.5 released in 2006, or in a later version, this type is called long and is separated from the int type, but the interpreter will automatically use the more appropriate type.​​​ In Python, you only need to perform standard mathematical operations, and any numbers beyond the 32-bit limit will be automatically and transparently converted to bignum.

You can find the [List of libraries that support "bignum" arithmetic for various programming languages at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Comment: I still confused, as I already using hash function MD5 on message and output 128 bits value.  And all my calculation is based on this128 bits value. I edit my question and try to make it more clear. The 'bignum' calculation appeared when calculating v2.

Comment: @BohuaJia Please create a new question about "pow", since you have edited your question after a substantial reply have been posted, so the reply is no longer relevant after your edit. The initial question was about big numbers in general and their speed, while after the edit it turned out to be an entirely new question that invalidates the reply posted before your edit. Even if you found a solution, you can submit your question as a new entry, but clearly state (e.g. in the title) that it is an application of the Python pow() function for digital signature.

Comment: @BohuaJia Also, please post your new question as text, not as an image.